# How do I interleave these processes?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm just starting to learn about interleaving and I have a program with the two following processes:

Process # 1:

```
    shared int x;
    x = 7;
    while true {
       x = x - 1;
       x = x + 1;
       if (x != 7)
          printf("x is %d", x);
```

Process # 2:

```
    shared int x:
    x = 7;
    while true {
       x = x - 1;
       x = x + 1;
       if (x != 7)
          printf("x is %d", x);
```

If there were no restrictions on the order of the interleaving, how can I order or interleave these two processes so that "x is 7" is printed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The process that prints "x is 7" would have to "see" that x is not-7 at the moment it executes its if-test, but then x would have to become 7 by the time `printf()` reads its value to print it out.  So, something like:

```
Process #1:   x = x - 1;  // x becomes 6
Process #2:   x = x - 1;  // x becomes 5
Process #1:   x = x + 1;  // x becomes 6
Process #1:   if (x != 7) // if-test succeeds, because x is 6
Process #2:   x = x + 1;  // x becomes 7
Process #1:   printf("x is %d", x);  // prints "x is 7"
```

Note that this is just one way the above could happen; especially if `x` isn't being modified atomically, there are numerous other ways in which things could get weird as well, due to register allocations, CPU cache interactions, the compiler optimizing and re-ordering the code using the "as-if" rule, etc.

Comment: With the fourth line, where x becomes 6, won't it print "x is 6" before proceeding to the fifth and sixth lines?

Comment: If the executions were interleaved such that that Process #1 gets to execute the printf() before Process #2 gets to execute its increment, then it might do that, but as you say there are no restrictions on the interleaving, therefore there is no guarantee that things would execute in that order.

Comment: Ah, right. So, just to clarify, once the if-test has succeeded in the fourth line from x = 6, I can then jump to Process # 2, where I can increment it to 7, and then print via the command in Process # 1 (after being "granted access" to the if-statement previously)? So, essentially we're kind of tricking it in a way.

Comment: Yes, a context-switch can happen at any time, even "inside lines".  (Keep in mind that many/most C++ statements translate into multiple CPU opcodes, and that a context switch can occur after any opcode, not only at certain points in the source code -- for example, 'x = x + 1' might compile to opcodes like:  "load the value of x from RAM into a CPU-register; add 1 to the value in the CPU-register; save the value in the CPU-register back to RAM", and a context-switch might well occur between two of those three opcodes)